# Magento2 Stripe Extension returns: Uncaught Error: Class 'Stripe\PaymentIntent' not found

Tags: magento2, error, payment-methods, payment-gateway, stripe

I've installed the Magento2 Stripe extension following this guide: https://stripe.com/docs/plugins/magento/install#manual

The extension is active and I've setup Stripe to send test data. The problem is when I go to the checkout and place the order the following call to `http://app.test/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/oza7bFkKh19JjTYedtbp9AyuneWJjtc9/payment-information` returns an error:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Stripe\PaymentIntent' not found in C:\laragon\www\app\code\StripeIntegration\Payments\Model\PaymentIntent.php:149
Stack trace:
#0 C:\laragon\www\app\code\StripeIntegration\Payments\Model\PaymentIntent.php(612): StripeIntegration\Payments\Model\PaymentIntent-&gt;create(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Interceptor))
#1 C:\laragon\www\app\code\StripeIntegration\Payments\Model\PaymentMethod.php(232): StripeIntegration\Payments\Model\PaymentIntent-&gt;confirmAndAssociateWithOrder(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Interceptor))
#2 C:\laragon\www\generated\code\StripeIntegration\Payments\Model\PaymentMethod\Interceptor.php(50): StripeIntegration\Payments\Model\PaymentMethod-&gt;capture(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Interceptor), '59.98')
#3 C:\laragon\www\vendor\magento\module-sales\Model\Order\Payment\Operations\CaptureOperation.php(82): StripeIntegration\Payments\Model\PaymentMethod in <b>C:\laragon\www\app\code\StripeIntegration\Payments\Model\PaymentIntent.php</b> on line <b>149</b><br />
{"messages":{"error":[{"code":500,"message":"Fatal Error: 'Uncaught Error: Class 'Stripe\\PaymentIntent' not found in C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\code\\StripeIntegration\\Payments\\Model\\PaymentIntent.php:149\nStack trace:\n#0 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\code\\StripeIntegration\\Payments\\Model\\PaymentIntent.php(612): StripeIntegration\\Payments\\Model\\PaymentIntent->create(Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Interceptor), Object(Magento\\Sales\\Model\\Order\\Payment\\Interceptor))\n#1 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\code\\StripeIntegration\\Payments\\Model\\PaymentMethod.php(232): StripeIntegration\\Payments\\Model\\PaymentIntent->confirmAndAssociateWithOrder(Object(Magento\\Sales\\Model\\Order\\Interceptor), Object(Magento\\Sales\\Model\\Order\\Payment\\Interceptor))\n#2 C:\\laragon\\www\\generated\\code\\StripeIntegration\\Payments\\Model\\PaymentMethod\\Interceptor.php(50): StripeIntegration\\Payments\\Model\\PaymentMethod->capture(Object(Magento\\Sales\\Model\\Order\\Payment\\Interceptor), '59.98')\n#3 C:\\laragon\\www\\vendor\\magento\\module-sales\\Model\\Order\\Payment\\Operations\\CaptureOperation.php(82): StripeIntegration\\Payments\\Model\\PaymentMethod' in 'C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\code\\StripeIntegration\\Payments\\Model\\PaymentIntent.php' on line 149","trace":"Trace is not available."}]}}
```

I can see in the Stripe webhook logs that the payment is being received also.

Have I missed something during the install step that's causing this to happen?

Comment: Hi, Did you find a solution to this issue? I have the same. I'm assuming it's an installation issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that the Stripe PHP library dependency was either not installed, or is out of date. You can try the following:

```
composer remove stripe/stripe-php
composer require stripe/stripe-php
```

This will install the latest version of the Stripe PHP library (but check which one is required by your installed module to be safe)